# jQuery validate plugin working only on last shown div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form that is a jQuery show/hide form. jQuery validate plugin only validates my last input on the last div (input type file). I can currently upload an image and submit the form successfully with the remaining inputs empty.

Below is the third div and when i click post ad with no inputs filled in, "This field is required" is shown.
[image: Third Div]

Below is the first div with no validation messages
[image: First Div]

Below is the second div with no validation messages
[image: Second Div]

Here is my form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

   <title>Zootopia</title>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form id="ad_form" method="post">

  <div id="ad_form_section1">

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="ad_title">Ad Title</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control stored" id="ad_title" placeholder="e.g. German Sheperd puppy - 4 months old" name="ad_title" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="description">Describe what you're offering</label>
       <textarea class="form-control stored" id="description" rows="6" placeholder="e.g. Owner supervised visits, minimum 1hr bookings, play with my german sheperd puppy in my backyard" name="description" required></textarea>
    </div>

  <button type="button" id="ad_section2" class="btn btn-primary"> Next </button>

  </div>

  <div id="ad_form_section2">

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="location"> Location</label>
       <input type="text" id="location_ad" class="form-control stored" placeholder="location" name="location" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="price">Price</label>
       <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control stored" name="price" placeholder="$0.00" required/>
    </div>

   <button type="button" id="back_section1" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </button>

   <button type="button" id="ad_section3" class="btn btn-primary"> Next </button>
  </div>

  <div id="ad_form_section3">

    <div>
       <label> Select pet pictures</label>
       <input type="file" name="multiple_files[]" id="multiple_files" multiple required/>
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="back_section2" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </button>

    <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="add" />

    <input type="submit" id="ad_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post ad" />

  </div>

</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ad_section2").click(function(){
      $("#ad_form_section1").hide();
      $("#ad_form_section2").show();
  });

  $("#back_section1").click(function(){
      $("#ad_form_section1").show();
      $("#ad_form_section2").hide();
  });

  $("#ad_section3").click(function(){
      $("#ad_form_section3").show();
      $("#ad_form_section2").hide();
  });

  $("#back_section2").click(function(){
      $("#ad_form_section2").show();
      $("#ad_form_section3").hide();
  });

    $("#ad_form").validate({
        rules:{
              ad_title:{
                required: true
              },
              description:{
                required: true
              },
              location:{
                required: true
              }
        },
        messages:{
              ad_title: {
                required: "please enter an ad title"
              },
              description: {
                required: "please enter a description"
              },
              location: {
                required: "please enter a location"
              }
        },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              var petID = $( "#pet_ad option:selected" ).val();
              var addAdUrl = "../../controller/post_ad_process.php?petID=" + petID;

                   $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                      url:addAdUrl,
                      type:"post",
                      datatype: 'json',
                      success: function(result){
                          if(result.petAd == false){
                            alert("Pet ad already exists!");
                          }else{
                            alert("Ad posted!");
                            $('#image_table').hide();
                          }
                      },
                      error: function(error) {
                        alert("Error");
                      }
                  });
            }
      });
})
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#ad_form_section2,
#ad_form_section3{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Any questions about how to use Stack Overflow and its features/functions should only be asked on the [SO Meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: You should be editing or closing your original question before posting it again.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sparky as i said i am very new to asking questions on stack overflow so I didn't actually know i can go and edit/delete a question that has already been posted. i'll keep this in mind for next time!

Comment: @Sparky: The earlier question has been automatically deleted. Would it make sense to reopen this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a condition before you show/hide next fields

```
if ( $('field-id').valid() ) {
     // Code 
}
```

For example:

```
$("#ad_section2").click(function(){
   if ($('#ad_title').valid() && $('#description').valid()) {
      $("#ad_form_section1").hide();
      $("#ad_form_section2").show();
    }
});
```

Also, don't forget to set character encoding to avoid characters range error, Add the following code just below `<head>` tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

**Form Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#ad_form").validate({
    rules:{
      ad_title:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 3, // set minimum title length
      },
      description:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
      },
      location:{
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages:{
      ad_title: {
        required: "please enter an ad title",
        minlength: "Your title must be more than 3 characters!",
      },
      description: {
        required: "please enter a description",
         minlength: "Your description must be at least 10 characters long",
      },
      location: {
        required: "please enter a location"
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var petID = $( "#pet_ad option:selected" ).val();
      var addAdUrl = "../../controller/post_ad_process.php?petID=" + petID;

      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        url:addAdUrl,
        type:"post",
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(result){
          if(result.petAd == false){
            alert("Pet ad already exists!");
          }else{
            alert("Ad posted!");
            $('#image_table').hide();
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("Error");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $("#ad_section2").click(function(){
    // Check if valid before show/hide
    if ($('#ad_title').valid() && $('#description').valid()) {
      $("#ad_form_section1").hide();
      $("#ad_form_section2").show();
    }
  });

  $("#back_section1").click(function(){
    $("#ad_form_section1").show();
    $("#ad_form_section2").hide();
  });

  $("#ad_section3").click(function(){
  // Check if valid before show/hide
    if ($('#location_ad').valid()) {
      $("#ad_form_section3").show();
      $("#ad_form_section2").hide();
    }
  });

  $("#back_section2").click(function(){
    $("#ad_form_section2").show();
    $("#ad_form_section3").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#ad_form_section2,
#ad_form_section3 {
  display: none;
}
label.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="ad_form" method="post">

    <div id="ad_form_section1">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ad_title">Ad Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control stored" id="ad_title" placeholder="e.g. German Sheperd puppy - 4 months old" name="ad_title">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Describe what you're offering</label>
        <textarea class="form-control stored" id="description" rows="6" placeholder="e.g. Owner supervised visits, minimum 1hr bookings, play with my german sheperd puppy in my backyard" name="description" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="ad_section2" class="btn btn-primary"> Next </button>
    </div>

    <div id="ad_form_section2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="location"> Location</label>
        <input type="text" id="location_ad" class="form-control stored" placeholder="location" name="location" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control stored" name="price" placeholder="$0.00" required/>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="back_section1" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </button>
      <button type="button" id="ad_section3" class="btn btn-primary"> Next </button>
    </div>

    <div id="ad_form_section3">
      <div>
        <label> Select pet pictures</label>
        <input type="file" name="multiple_files[]" id="multiple_files" multiple required/>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="back_section2" class="btn btn-primary"> Back </button>
      <input type="hidden" name="action_type" value="add" />
      <input type="submit" id="ad_button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post ad" />
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**More examples from [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)**

Comment: thanks for your help! i managed to get the validation functioning but now my ajax is not recognising my input values in form 1 and form 2. I know i need to change my php processing file but unsure how.

Comment: Do you have any log error? Please follow these examples [here](https://gist.github.com/jakebellacera/839163) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361231/submit-form-with-ajax-and-jquery-validation)

Comment: i just looked at those examples and attempted them to no avail haha i think i need to see the PHP file as I think I am passing the data incorrectly into ajax

Answer (score 1):

By default the plugin is going to ignore any/all fields that are hidden. You have to set to the `ignore` option to "nothing".

```
$("#ad_form").validate({
    ignore: [],  // ignore nothing, validate everything
    rules:{
        ad_title:{ ....
```

If you're expecting validation when you show/hide sections of the form, that's not how it works.  You're going to have to programmatically trigger validation on the relevant fields as you click back and forth.  Use [the `.valid()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) for this.

However, multi-step validation can quickly get tedious so you may have to re-think your entire approach.  I personally like to enclose each section within its own set of `<form></form>` tags so I can control validation on each step separately.

Here's one example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20481497/594235